# Architectural guidance for an eBay-like "Contact Us" system with a decision "workflow"

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

I am creating a new support center and "self-help" customer service module for an application.  The CIO really likes the flow of eBay's "Contact Us" pages, that basically work like this:

- First, you select a specific topic from a group of topics (e.g. Buying, Selling, Account on eBay)
- You're then presented with what appears to be one of three variable types of information, based on the topic you picked (names are just what I'm calling them in some preliminary sketches):

  1. "Descriptive": displays rich text with possible links to other parts of the application.
  2. "Choice": Displays a list of additional topics
  3. "Action": Lets the user look up an item and do some action (e.g. cancel)

From some experimentation, a choice can list to other choices, or to a descriptive block of text, or to an action section.

I'm turning up blanks as to the proper architecture for this.  My platform of choice is ASP.NET (WebForms, sadly; we have no desire to touch MVC here) so the "Action" areas would have to be a user control that's dynamically loaded into a placeholder, but I'm more concerned with a possible database structure for this.  I would need a way to know if each topic leads to one of the three types above and then on the page dynamically load either the content, list of links, or user control which makes things a bit trickier, nevermind the fact that a non-technical user will have to update and add the information from some kind of administrative panel.

Any suggestions for doing something like this?  I'm not on a tight deadline, but I can't take too long or I'll be considered to be wasting time and not producing results.

Comment: Are your constraints ASP.NET or specifically ASP.NET webforms?

Comment: WebForms, sadly.  Cannot introduce MVC here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can store the "tree of knowledge" in some way, like a custom XML file which would organize all options / possible actions, descriptions etc. Then you can "walk" it based on user's selections and display appropriate user control with content generated on the fly based on the contents of the XML node you're currently at.

Your "admin tool" would then need to update/modify the XML file, and your "public" CMS would render user controls inside an ASPX form.

One of the projects I worked on used this methodology for intranet's user menu - effectively a knowledge base of hyperlinks / actions split in to categories so they can be drilled-down to. Each element can contain links to other elements - so you have a spider-web like navigatable chain / workflow.

Just make sure each element has a unique ID (trivial to implement) and you can always get at it through xpath.

By having users modify a "working copy" and keeping backups of the live XML file when changes are published you also get versioning / roll-back which would be difficult to do in a DB.

Answer (score 0):

If I personally was doing this I would just roll some MVC3 controllers that handle the work flow steps as needed. That seems to be out for you however.

With webforms, I would most likely consider handling this using Windows Workflow Foundation (the learning curve is moderately steep on this). Here's a pretty good example on using WF [Flexible Web UI Workflow application through ASP.NET MVC & Windows Workflow Foundation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/flexible_web_UI.aspx). It's built on MVC however you could easily replace the return Views() with return UserControls.

Following a model like this would defacto give you the MVC pattern. The controller dictating flow matches very well for a workflow scenario.

**Edit:** Since this even seems out of the question, at this point you're best option is just writing a controller class that will manage the flow manually (probably a bunch of state / if checks) and then redirect users or return the appropriate user control.

Comment: I'll take a look, but honestly I don't think I can get approval to introduce Workflow, or hell introduce anything new (I had to fight tooth and nail to get approval to use Linq to Sql instead of raw untyped DataSets + sprocs) - management seems to think it's a very simple set of pages/conditionals so I might have to compromise somehow and make my version **very** simplistic to be able to realistically do it.

Comment: Sounds like you came to SO just to make yourself feel bad for all the things you **can't** do.

Comment: More like hoping there would be a simple way to handle the problem, I should have known better :)

Comment: The most appropriate solution in all avenues is the Controller class dictating flow.